# Best class structure practice for step by step object manipulation in python

Tags: python, class, syntax

Hi I want to create a class with multiple methods. Each method depends on the result of another method. A simplified example looks like:

```
class klass(object):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.results = 0

def method1(self):
    self.results = self.x + self.y
    return self.results

def method2(self):
    self.results = math.sqrt(self.results)
    return self.results
```

*method2* should called only after *method1*. i.e:

```
>>> b=klass(3.0, 4.0)
>>> b.method1()
7.0
>>> b.method2()
2.6457513110645907
```

The idea is that someone may need only the result of *method1* and someone else may need the result of *method2* as well. So the first person needs to run only *method1* and the second person needs to run *method1* and then *method2*.

What is the best(most readable and simplest) way  to do that.

Note that this is a much more simple version of a complex class

Answer (score 1):

I would switch results to be a dictionary and save the results for each level separately. Then you can check in each method `if "level1" not in self.results: raise an exception` but then you can still provide the output of each level to users. Furthermore you could start each method by checking to see if the results exist already. An example would be like so:

```
class klass(object):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.results = {"level0": 0}

def method1(self):
    if "level1" not in self.results:
        self.results["level1"] = self.x + self.y
    return self.results["level1"]

def method2(self):
    if "level1" not in self.results:
        raise ValueError("The results of method1 are not yet available")
    if "level2" not in self.results:
        self.results["level2"] = math.sqrt(self.results["level1"])
    return self.results["level2"]
```

P.S. Don't use the name `klass`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm getting this wrong, but couldn't you just call method1 in method2 like this:

```
def method2(self):
    self.method1()
    self.results = math.sqrt(self.results)
    return self.results
```

Comment: Yes that's true. But this will slow down my code. i.e in cases where someone needs method1 and after some time needs method2 as well, it will be more optimal to not run method1 again (since it is already calculated and saved).

Comment: But thats just a quick check with a boolean variable that you set when method1 has been executed, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate functions to aggregate functions you need in a single place:

```
class klass(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.results = 0

    def method1(self):
        self.results = self.x + self.y
        return self.results

    def method2(self):
        self.results = math.sqrt(self.results)
        return self.results

    def both_methods(self):
        self.method1()
        self.method2()
        return self.results
```